# Hanging up blackboard adhesive over a rough textured wall

Tags: walls, mounting

Following from [this thread](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/30006/should-we-skim-coat-or-drywall-over-a-textured-plaster-wall-to-smooth-it-out), what would be the best way to "smooth" my wall to hang some [blackboard adhesive paper](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000KKMO90) over it?

Comment: Is this intended to be permanent? The blackboard paper you linked to looks like it is for more temporary uses.  It might just be easier to hang a blackboard on the wall.

Comment: There's also blackboard paint (although most companies call it 'chalkboard paint')

Comment: Oh yes it's just temporary. For 3 months.

Answer (score 1):

A $15 bucket of drywall compound (mud) and a wide drywall knife, a wall sanding block and some drywall sanding screens. Even as a temporary fix, unless you want to hang up a chalkboard as suggested in the comments, the skim-coat of drywall mud will get the job done as quickly and easily as it can be done. If you'll be doing the work in 3 months, it will also provide hands-on practice that you don't have to care about being "perfect" if you'll be ripping and replacing in 3 months. As suggested in that thread, try sanding off the high points before you start mudding.

Big hint if you haven't done much - do **not** try to get it perfect in one coat. The secret to quick and easy mudwork is to **let it dry**, knock off the high points, and recoat to fill the low spots, repeatedly.

Comment: This is for a temporary apartment. Is the method you've described permanently damaging to the walls?

Comment: The post **you** referred to spoke of permanently changing the walls. If your application is different, then you need to hang up a blackboard (or a hang up a sheet of tempered hardboard and apply your blackboard paper to that.) If you're going to provide misleading background information and fail to explain how your case is different, the applicability of advice to your question will tend to stink...you appeared to be asking about a 3-month solution until you got around to re-texturing all the walls, not an apartment.